# Multi-state Jetpack Compose Screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I have screen that should display one three things: (I'm also very new to Jetpack Compose)

A Loader() if loading
An AlertDialog() if there's an error
And finally, based on an int from my viewModel, a new ScreenX()

I make an API call in my viewModel and update the 3 state variables accordingly.
The problem is that all of the views seem to be appearing over top of each other.

If I try and `return Loader()`, I get an error.

Maybe this isn't the correct way to do this, but is there any way you can
have dynamic screens in a Composable?

```
@Composable
fun ConnectionScreen(
    ip: String,
    viewModel: BridgeViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val page = viewModel.page.collectAsState()
    val loading = viewModel.loading.collectAsState()
    val error = viewModel.error.collectAsState()

    Scaffold {
        if (loading.value) {
            Loader()
        }

        error.value?.let {
            AlertDialogWithButtons(
                title = "Error",
                message = it,
                onNegativeClick = { },
                onPositiveClick = {},
            )
        }

        when (page.value) {
            0 -> Screen0() 
            1 -> Screen1() 
            2 -> Screen2()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create an encapsulating data class to better represent UI state. It's not the best, and unfortunately not reusable (I'll need to create a new data class for every screen? Even though most will be using an API, so Loading and Error should be reusable).

```
enum class ResourceState { LOADING, ERROR, LINK, FINISH }

data class CreateResourceState(
    val loading: Boolean = false,
    val error: String? = null,
    val page: Int = 0,
) {
    val state: ResourceState
        get() {
            return if (loading) ResourceState.LOADING
            else if (error != null) ResourceState.ERROR
            else if (page == 1) ResourceState.LINK
            else if (page == 2) ResourceState.FINISH
            else ResourceState.LOADING
        }
}
```

Then in my ViewModel

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(CreateResourceState(loading = true))
val uiState: StateFlow<CreateResourceState> = _uiState

...

_uiState.value = CreateResourceState(error = exception.message)

...

_uiState.value = CreateResourceState(page = 1)
```

Finally in the UI

```
val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

when (uiState.value.state) {
    ResourceState.LOADING -> Loader()
    ResourceState.ERROR -> ErrorDialog()
    ResourceState.LINK -> Screen1()
    ResourceState.FINISH -> Screen2()
}
```

It still seems weird to me that you can *only* return *one and only one* Composable. Maybe I'm too used to Flutter, where you can dynamically return any Widget at any time inside of another Widget.

Comment: I completely do not understand what do you mean by "you can return one composable. Composable is nothing but a function, you can do absolutely anything you want with it

Answer (score 0):

There is this bug (I'm pretty sure we can call it that since it crashes whole app with meaningless error message) where you cannot `return` from the insides of a lambda inside layout composable. So if you do this:

```kotlin
Column {
  if (variable){
    return 
  }
  Text("test")
}
```

if the `variable` is true - compose hard crashes. I'm trying to find if there is a bug report for that. In the meantime - there are 2 things you can do to avoid that:

You can move your code to function, like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ConnectionScreen(
    ip: String,
    viewModel: BridgeViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    Scaffold {
        Content(viewModel)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Content(viewModel: BridgeViewModel) {
    val page = viewModel.page.collectAsState()
    val loading = viewModel.loading.collectAsState()
    val error = viewModel.error.collectAsState()
    if (loading.value) {
            Loader()
        }

        error.value?.let {
            AlertDialogWithButtons(
                title = "Error",
                message = it,
                onNegativeClick = { },
                onPositiveClick = {},
            )
        }

        when (page.value) {
            0 -> Screen0() 
            1 -> Screen1() 
            2 -> Screen2()
        }
{
```

Or you can stick to `if-else`, like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ConnectionScreen(
    ip: String,
    viewModel: BridgeViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val page = viewModel.page.collectAsState()
    val loading = viewModel.loading.collectAsState()
    val error = viewModel.error.collectAsState()

    Scaffold {
        if (loading.value) {
            Loader()
        } else {
            error.value?.let {
                AlertDialogWithButtons(
                    title = "Error",
                    message = it,
                    onNegativeClick = { },
                    onPositiveClick = {},
                )
            }

            when (page.value) {
                0 -> Screen0() 
                1 -> Screen1() 
                2 -> Screen2()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't too successful with the first option, but the if-else put me on the right track. I posted my final solution above